# Why pip does not install a package?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

`pip install` indicates that the `nitime` package was successfully installed but it is not. Why is this?

```
$ pip3 install nitime
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting nitime
  Using cached nitime-0.9.tar.gz (6.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nitime) (1.22.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from nitime) (0.29.14)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nitime) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from nitime) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nitime) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: nibabel in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nitime) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->nitime) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->nitime) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->nitime) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib->nitime) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from networkx->nitime) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=14.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nibabel->nitime) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nibabel->nitime) (60.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib->nitime) (1.14.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for nitime, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: nitime
  Running setup.py install for nitime ... done
Successfully installed nitime
$ pip3 show nitime
WARNING: Package(s) not found: nitime
$ python3 -c "import nitime"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nitime'


$ pip3 show pip
Name: pip
Version: 22.0.4
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /home/servoz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 
$ uname -a
Linux 5.11.22-100.fc32.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 19 18:58:25 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.10
```

**EDIT:**
Ok! I managed to install using `dnf install python3-nitime` (fedora).

I don't really understand why pip doesn't work with nitime on fedora ...

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling it? Often works if its just python being abit slow

Comment: you could also have different python3.X-versions which are in "conflict"? like you installed for python3.8 but currently you are using python3.9

Comment: @MaxVK, just tested. not better!

Comment: @y.y, I edited the question. I use python3.8!

Comment: Why is pip installed in /home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages? There is a missing username inside /home in that path.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, You are right ... I removed my name from the path :-)

Comment: change it to something like user, if not it becomes confusing.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy,  done ...

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of conflicts with other packages, so try doing this in a new environment. Try creating a virtual environment. Install `virtualenv` using this:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Create a virtual environment named `venv` using this:

```
virtualenv venv
```

To activate the virtual environment, use this:

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Try installing `nitime` now:

```
pip3 install nitime
```

Done!

You can deactivate the virtual environment using this:

```
deactivate
```

Comment: thanks for virtualenv, which I know (I also managed to install nitime in a singularity container). But here the question is why pip says it has successfully installed a package when it is not true ...